# Access VBA Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've been searching the net on how to run a query in Access using VBA & SQL and come up with this. The general idea is that the value selected from the combo box should run a query based on the ID Selected for instance. The user selects a company which has an ID of 5 in the companies table. This then populates the text boxes below with the relevant data. I also have another table with employee data in which has a relationship with the companies tables using the CompanyID as the primary key, if the employees company id = 5 they work for asda in this case. For some reason when running this query i'm receiving an error stating that there may have been an errro evaluating the function

```
Public Function DataLookup()
Dim CompDetailSQL As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim CompID As String
CompID = Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT Companies.CompanyID, Companies.CompanyName,       Companies.AddressNo, Companies.AddressLine1, Companies.AddressLine2, Companies.AddressLine3, Companies.AddressPostcode, Companies.AddressCounty, Link_Table.FirstName, Link_Table.LastName FROM Companies INNER JOIN Link_Table ON Companies.CompanyID = Link_Table.CompanyID WHERE " = CompID
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(CompDetailSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
Me.lblAddressLine1.Value = rst!Companies.AddressLine1
Me.lblAddressLine2.Value = rst!Companies.AddressLine2
Me.lblAddressLine3.Value = rst!Companies.AddressLine3
Me.lblAddressPostcode.Value = rst!Companies.AddressPostcode
Me.lblAddressCounty.Value = rst!Companies.AddressCounty
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers guys problem solved. The SQL query itself wouldn't run under access query design.

```
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT Companies.CompanyID, 
Companies.CompanyName, 
Companies.AddressNo, 
Companies.AddressLine1, 
Companies.AddressLine2, 
Companies.AddressLine3, 
Companies.AddressPostcode, 
Companies.AddressCounty,
Link_Table.FirstName, 
Link_Table.LastName
FROM Companies 
INNER JOIN 
Link_Table ON Companies.CompanyID = Link_Table.CompanyID 
WHERE Companies.CompanyID = " & Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value
```

However the query above did work, it seemed i was missing `Companies.CompanyID` Problem solved which now creates a new problem. But a completely different question. Thank you for your help @hansUp @bamie9l

Comment: You're very welcome :) and I think you can accept your own answers

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a problem here ...

```vb
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT ... WHERE " = CompID
```

Whether or not it throws an error, I suspect that `WHERE` clause will not do what you need.

Give yourself an opportunity to examine the completed SQL statement your code creates.  Include this line after `CompDetailSQL = ...`

```vb
Debug.Print CompDetailSQL
```

Afterwards, run the code and go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to view the output.  You can copy the statement text and then paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.

When you have the query you need, then reference the recordset fields by field name ... not qualified with the name of the source table.

```vb
'rst!Companies.AddressLine1
rst!AddressLine1
```

You said populate text boxes.  If `lblAddressLine1` is really a text box, this should work ...

```vb
Me.lblAddressLine1.Value = rst!AddressLine1
```

However, if `lblAddressLine1` is actually a label control, set its `.Caption` instead of `.Value` property.

```vb
Me.lblAddressLine1.Caption = rst!AddressLine1
```

Comment: The immediate window is showing false? This meaning that the query, returns no data?

Comment: I concur with Hans' advice, however in addition I think you've missed out whatever the compID column is, so instead of saying "Where ComputerID = " & compID you have just "Where = " &  compID

Comment: Of course!  Sorry I didn't spot that sooner.  Your code asks VBA whether "SELECT ..." is equal to `CompID`.  But the string is not equal to that number, so the result of that expression is `False` which is then converted to a text value and stored in `CompDetailSQL`.

Comment: bamie91 is right.  Fix your code to construct the SQL statement you need.  This is the first problem you must solve.  Keep at it until `Debug.Print` shows you a SQL statement which works correctly when you test it as a new Access query.

Comment: I've ran the debugger as stated above and the debugger stated false. Played around with the code, and changed it to perform a query on only the single table and it completes without error. The error seems to be when performing a query on the two tables.

Comment: Add the problem SQL statement to your question and tell us the full text of the error message you get from the db engine.

Comment: changing the code too..
`CompDetailSQL = "SELECT Companies.CompanyID, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.AddressNo, Companies.AddressLine1, Companies.AddressLine2, Companies.AddressLine3, Companies.AddressPostcode, Companies.AddressCounty, Link_Table.FirstName, Link_Table.LastName FROM Companies INNER JOIN Link_Table ON Companies.CompanyID = Link_Table.CompanyID = " & Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value
Debug.Print CompDetailSQL
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(CompDetailSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)`

Comment: `SELECT Companies.CompanyID, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.AddressNo, Companies.AddressLine1, Companies.AddressLine2, Companies.AddressLine3, Companies.AddressPostcode, Companies.AddressCounty, Link_Table.FirstName, Link_Table.LastName FROM Companies INNER JOIN Link_Table ON Companies.CompanyID = Link_Table.CompanyID = 5`